# ASP.NET call button action from different class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I have a class Lot with a function AddPiece(piece).

I also have a Page with a button btnPanel that on click fires the function

```
public void btnPanel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e){}
```

I want to call the btnPanel_OnClick from the Addpiece function but when I try to do it it does not show in the intlliSense and I get this compilation error "The name 'btnPanel_OnClick' does not exist in the current context". Both classes are in the same namespace. Is this possible?

Here is what I have:

```
namespace GraphicW_Array
{
  public partial class Board : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public void btnPanel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ...code...
     }
   }
 }
```

and

```
namespace GraphicW_Array
{
  public class Lot
  {
    public void addPiece(int piece)
    {
        lotPresent[lotLoad] = piece;
        lotLoad++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, what happens if you try it?

Comment: @KeithIrwin "The name 'btnPanel_OnClick' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Then they are not in the same namespace.

Comment: keep in mind that it is a horrible idea to call event handlers for form controls from separate classes. Do you have any reason why you want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is yes you can but you probably don't want to. To call the method you need and instance of your page class so you could do

```
namespace GraphicW_Array
{
  public class Lot
  {
    public void addPiece(int piece)
    {
        lotPresent[lotLoad] = piece;
        lotLoad++;
        var myPage = new Board();
        myPage.btnPanel_OnClick(null,EventArgs.Empty);
    }
  }
}
```

But what would that actually do?  I have no idea because you haven't posted the code but i suspect it won't do anything useful for you.

What are you actually trying to achieve?

Maybe this is want you want

```
namespace GraphicW_Array
    {
      public class Lot
      {
        public void addPiece(int piece, Board myPAge)
        {
            lotPresent[lotLoad] = piece;
            lotLoad++;
            myPage.btnPanel_OnClick(null,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
      }
    }
```

Then in your page you can call it like this:

```
var myLot = new Lot();
myLot.addPiece(4,this);
```

Comment: Actually is more like the first code that you show. I don't want to call the class function from the button but YES want to call the button from the class function

Comment: Where do you want to call the addPiece method from? Obviously it is not within the btnPanel_OnClick method as that would create an infinite loop in the second bit of my code. The first piece of code will "work" in that it will call the method, i just doubt it is really what you want as it can't imagine it will do anything useful.

Comment: If you are going to call the button's OnClick method then you should pass in the actual sender in for consistency and prevent an unnecessary null reference. Either `this` for (`Lot` instance) or `myPage.btnPanel`, whichever makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

Ensure your `Lot` class has a reference to the `Board` class in order to be able to call it, or define an event on it that the `Board` class can subscribe to and that will call this mathod when the event fires.

If you don't use the `sender` and `e` parameters, just pass a `null` and `EventArgs.Empty`.

Comment: @NicoTek - Well, you need your `Lot` class to have a reference to the `Board` class, or else it won't be able to call anything.

Answer (score 1):

You can call page's event by passing either null(if sender and EventArgs is not mandatory) but below is the better way to go.

It is not wise and not good practice to call a event from a class, however you can create another method with arguments in your class and then call it with desired parameters when it is needed.

This is can be accomplished as below:

Say you have below event

```
public void btnPanel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do some common tasks to do here
}
```

Rearrange it as below:

```
public void btnPanel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Lot lot = new Lot();
    lot.CommonFunction(arg1, arg2); // Pass required data
}

public class Lot
{
    public void AFunction()
    {
         //Do something
         //...
         CommonFunction(arg1, arg2); // Pass required data
         //...
         //Do something
    }

    public void CommonFunction(string arg1, string arg2)
    {
        // Do some common tasks to do here
    }
}
```